Robust standard errors SPSS
I am running various linear regressions on SPSS - this is exploratory rather than trying to prove a specific hypothesis for reference. Some of the dependent variables have an element of heteroskedasticity, so have ran a univariate analysis to get 'parameter estimates with robust standard errors' for the runs that are experiencing this heteroskedasticity.
Now obviously this produces some different outputs compared to the linear regression outputs. The statistical significance of some of the independent variables has changed as a result. Should the significance from the robust standard errors be prioritised over the linear regression outputs? Or would it 'acceptable'/still good statistical practice to only take the standard errors from those outputs and proceed with the linear regression significance?
For context, I am just generally trying to understand the relationship between the independent and dependent variables better, rather than making specific conclusions.
Any guidance would go a long way!
